# Can't connect using NordVPN

Tags: vpn

I'm getting a "transport is closing" error when trying to use

```
nordvpn connect uk
```

I've tried these 2 commands from https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/nordvpn-bin/

```
sudo systemctl enable --now nordvpnd
```

and

```
sudo systemctl start nordvpnd
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

I tried setting the protocol to TCP:

```
nordvpn settings

Protocol: TCP
Kill Switch: disabled
CyberSec: disabled
Obfuscate: enabled
Auto connect: disabled
DNS: disabled
```

Any ideas?

Edit: 2019-04-05

I'm getting a different error message now but still unable to connect:

```
nordvpn connect uk
Connecting to United Kingdom #513 (uk513.nordvpn.com)
Whoops! We can't connect you to 'uk513.nordvpn.com'. Please try again. If the problem persists, contact our customer support.

nordvpn connect de
Connecting to Germany #316 (de316.nordvpn.com)
Whoops! We can't connect you to 'de316.nordvpn.com'. Please try again. If the problem persists, contact our customer support.
```

Comment: Had the same issue too yesterday with **de** servers. But **ch** was working fine. Didn't have this before, maybe it was a temporary issue?

Comment: Seems to be some block intentional - they think there's invalid traffic so they are slowing you down.

Comment: try change technologies: "$ nordvpn set technology nordlynx". If you want to change it back to openvpn: "$ nordvpn set technology openvpn" (sorry for bad formatting, not enough karma to post a decent reply...

Answer (score 6):

There was an update of the NordVPN package today, now it's working fine again.

If you installed via the nordvpn repo, you can run this:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: Woohoo!!! It's fixed, cheers dude :)

Comment: @RussellEngland you can set the answer as the accepted one

Answer (score 3):

### Solution #1

First, try to re-install NordVPN.

To [uninstall NordVPN](https://support.nordvpn.com/General-info/1047410452/How-to-uninstall-NordVPN-software.htm), open a Terminal and type the following:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove nordvpn*
```

or

```
sudo dpkg -P nordvpn
sudo dpkg -P nordvpn-release
```

---

Now, [install NordVPN](https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Linux/1325531132/Installing-and-using-NordVPN-on-Debian-Ubuntu-and-Linux-Mint.htm) again:

1) Download the NordVPN Linux client from their official [downloads page](https://nordvpn.com/download/linux/) or click on [this](https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian/pool/main/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb) direct link.

Alternatively, you can use this command and proceed straight to the step 3:

```
sudo wget -qnc https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian/pool/main/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb
```

2) Open Terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i /pathToFile/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb
```

Make sure to replace */pathToFile/* with the path to your Downloads folder (or other location where the NordVPN file was downloaded).

**Example:**

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb
```

You will be asked to enter your root password. Enter it, wait for the package installation to finish, and proceed to the next step.

3) Update the package list:

```
sudo apt update
```

4) Install the NordVPN app:

```
sudo apt install nordvpn
```

5) Log in to your NordVPN account:

```
nordvpn login
```

6) Connect to a NordVPN server:

```
nordvpn connect
```

---

### Solution #2

If the issue persists, no matter what server you are trying to connect to, there is a chance that there is an issue with the permissions of `.config.ovpn`. Execute the following commands:

```
$ sudo chattr -i -a /var/lib/nordvpn/data/.config.ovpn

$ sudo chmod ugo+w /var/lib/nordvpn/data/.config.ovpn
```