# Cannot connect to NordVPN server

Tags: server, 20.04, vpn, openvpn

I have an issue with connecting to any NordVPN server on my Ubuntu Server 20.04. While I am trying to connect using
`nordvpn connect` command it is showing `Connecting to France #703 (fr703.nordvpn.com)` but then is nothing happening. No message that connection was successful or not.

I tried to reinstall NordVPN, and other things from this post [Can't connect using NordVPN](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130740/cant-connect-using-nordvpn) but it still is not working.

I tried to connect through OpenVPN with these steps https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Linux/1047409422/How-can-I-connect-to-NordVPN-using-Linux-Terminal.htm but I am getting this error. I tried few times and I am sure that credentials are correct.

`AUTH: Received control message: AUTH_FAILED`

Comment: Have you tried NordVPN's customer support?

Comment: Honestly, as a NordVPN user, their Linux support is abysmal. I realize this helps you exactly none, but it's the truth. I use their browser extensions and those work most of the time. Your best option is going to be to contact them, as already mentioned. Otherwise, their browser extensions are really the only reliable method of using their VPN on Linux. I stick with it because I subscribe to the service through an affiliate link for a site I enjoy and that's the only reason.

Comment: I've used NordVPN for two years and had no problem with it. Have you tried connecting to other servers than this particular one? If so, if both ways fail with that message and you're sure your credentials are fine, I would head for customer support indeed.

Comment: I have found their linux support to be superb.  they sent me this a  month ago and I have not tried it out yet.


"Would you like to try the manual connection out?"

You can follow our guide here: https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Linux/1047409422/How-can-I-connect-to-NordVPN-using-Linux-Terminal.htm