# nordvpn ubuntu error: Whoops ! Something went wrong

Tags: vpn

When I reboot my ubuntu 20.04 focal machine and do a `nordvpn connect`, I sometimes get this annoying nordvpn error.

```
Whoops! Something went wrong. Please try again. If the problem persists, contact our customer support.
```

[image]

> Whoops! Something went wrong. Please try again. If the problem persists, contact our customer support.

## Details

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please always copy the plain text instead of a screenshot of the terminal

Answer (score 1):

apparently re-installation seems to fix it.

[I got this from here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130740/cant-connect-using-nordvpn)

```
sudo dpkg -P nordvpn
sudo dpkg -P nordvpn-release
cd ~/Downloads 
sudo wget -qnc https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian/pool/main/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install nordvpn
nordvpn login
nordvpn connect
```

[image]